# Validation failed error due to square brackets in $ref - swagger 2.0 json generated by swashbuckle web api - While importing in API Management

Tags: swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

I am getting the following error in the **swagger 2.0 json** that gets auto-generated by **Swashbuckle WebApi** (ASP.NET WEB API .NET Framework project), when I import it into any API Management platform:

**Error:**
Validation failed. Definition names should match against: /^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+$/

The reason is presence of [ and ] brackets in the $ref.

I implemented IOperationFilter and have modified [ and ] brackets in Operation Response Definition Schema to characters allowed by Swagger 2.0 specs.

**E.g.**

My **original Operation definition** as auto-generated by Swashbuckle is as follows:

"/v1/api/configuration/notifications/schedules":{"get":{"tags":["Notifications"],"consumes":[],"produces":["application/json","text/json"],"responses":{"200":{"description":"OK","schema":{"**$ref**":"#/definitions/MyCompany.ItemsDTO **[** MyCompany.Web.API.Notifications.DTOs.NotificationModel **]**"}}}}}

**Notice the [ and ] brackets in bold in $ref above**.

I modified the $ref by implemeting IOperation filter.

**Modified Operation**:

"/v1/api/configuration/notifications/schedules":{"get":{"tags":["Notifications"],"consumes":[],"produces":["application/json","text/json"],"responses":{"200":{"description":"OK","schema":{"**$ref**":"#/definitions/MyCompany.ItemsDTO_ MyCompany.Web.API.Notifications.DTOs.NotificationModel"}}}}}

Please note that the **[** has been replaced by _ **(underscore)** , while **]** has been **removed**.

But I also need to make similar changes in Model Definition and any $refs in the Model Definition.

E.g.
**Model Definition:**

"definitions":{"MyCompany.ItemsDTO **[** MyCompany.Web.API.Notifications.DTOs.NotificationModel **]** ":{"type":"object","properties":{"MyNotificationTemplate":{"**$ref**":"#/definitions/MyCompany.ItemsDTO **[** DTOs.NotificationTemplateDTO **]** "}}}}

[] brackets in the above Model definition and its $ref highlighted in bold.

I have implemented ISchemaFilter and have created the Apply method:

```
public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, Type type)
{
}
```

I can check for **[** and **]** brackets in the **schema** object in the **Apply method**. But I will only be able to modify **[** and **]** in Model Definition's **$ref** but not the Model definition name (Key) because the Model Definition name (Key) is not a part of schema object.

Model Definition names(Keys) show up in the schemaRegistry object. But it is a Dictionary of all schemas and model is dynamically added to the schemaRegistry, whenever a new model is found.

If I do not modify the Model Definition name(Key) to match the $ref of Operation definition, then I will get "missing reference" error.

Any pointers on how to make the necessary changes in the Model Definition Schema.

**I have already tried the following:**

1. URL encoding [ and ] by %5B and %5D. **Get the same error when importing the swagger json in APIM**
2. Using HttpConfiguration.EnableSwagger(c => c.SchemaId(type => type.ToString().Replace("[", "*").Replace("]", "*").Replace(",", "-")); --> **It does not make any changes to Schema Definition**
3. Manually updating the swagger json to replace [ by _ and removing ] in the Model definition and it's $refs. **I was able to successfully import this file in APIM.**
   Now I am trying to automate the manual steps that I performed in #3.